# Moving multiple features to snap to nearest edge

Tags: arcgis-desktop, features, snapping, arcgis-10.3

I have thousands of long rectangular polygons which I need to align to a specific/nearest edge.  The screenshot below demonstrates what I need to achieve:

[image: Yellow and white dotted features need to **maintain original width** (1m) but move and snap to the nearest edge]

Yellow and white dotted features need to **maintain original width** (1m) but move and snap to the nearest edge.

I am working with ArcGIS 10.3.

I have looked at all of the Alignment Tools, but I'm just not clear on the best method.  I tried Align to Shape but this adjusts the width of the polygons.

Any clues?

Comment: It sounds like you want to _move_ the geometry so it aligns to that edge. But we need more context, are they always rectangular and needing to be move to a straight edge? What if the edge they are aligning to is curved?

Comment: Have a look at the spatial adjustment toolbar?

Comment: Yes, the features are always rectangular. To provide more context, the rectangles represent grass verge which is a meter wide and should align with the edge of the road. Unfortunately it doesn't. The edge of the road will vary, some sections might be straight, but many are curved.  I was wondering whether it would work by creating a buffer from the edge of the road, then intersect with the current inaccurate dataset?

Comment: Intersect will only keep the areas over overlap between the two. If you're wanting to completely recreate the verge, and it's always 1m wide and should always be immediately adjacent to the road, you could buffer the road and then replace the verge layer or import those features into that layers. But if there are other attributes and such, and particular breaks that need to be maintained, I suspect you have a lot of manual cleanup/editing ahead. Why should it align and doesn't (ie, is this an import issue, or shapefile trying to store true curves or what)?

Comment: You want to widen you polygons.  Based on my tests, the Align to Shape tool will widen the verge rectangles to touch the edge of the road.  Then you can buffer the Road 1 meter and intersect the widened verge polygons with the buffer.  The intersected buffer will be the width you want (1 meter) and be split perpendicular to the road at the rectangle edges and will have the attributes of the verge that you want.  At least try it on a small scale sample.  You want a widened road and a widened  aligned verge to intersect, which removes the road and the verge over 1 meter out.